# How is the damaged road restored to normal?

Tags: hellboy

In [*Hellboy* (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellboy_(2019_film)), Hellboy beheads the Blood Queen and at the same time on the earth, demons dragged to the bottom & the damaged road
got restored to normal.

[image: Demon drops through a hole in the road which seals itself up behind. The road also heals around an open, fiery manhole, which coughs up its cover and closes.]

How is that possible?

Comment: The same way they came up in the first place, magic.

Answer (score 4):

The [film script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/hellboy-2019.pdf) describes these as '*hell cracks*', cracks in the surface of the Earth that inexplicably (through the application of magic) extended directly into Hell, rather than into [what's usually there](https://www.fuseanimation.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/InteractiveWebExperience_WhatsUnderOurStreet.jpg).

When the Blood Queen is decapitated, the cracks begin to close because the power that sustains them has evidently been removed.

> **BLOOD QUEEN (CONT’D)** *NOOOOO!!!*
>
> Through the cathedral’s crumbling walls, we can see the storm subsiding. Rays of sunshine punch through the dissipating cloud cover, and the creatures of darkness flee in terror. The Giant Tentacles recede into the River Thames. And the hell beasts slip back into the cracks in the earth, which begin to seal shut behind them.
>
> **BLOOD QUEEN (CONT’D)** *You fool! What have you done!?! Fulfill your destiny!!*
>
> Hellboy, becoming his old self again, reaches up and takes hold of his horns, snapping them off at the base. He tosses them aside and picks up the Blood Queen’s severed head...
>
> **HELLBOY** *Anyone ever told you you talk too much?*
>
> ...THEN DROP KICKS it out of the cathedral and into one of the remaining hell cracks, which seals shut, taking the Blood Queen’s fading cries with it.